# BACnet deserialization: How do I know if a new list elements starts

Tags: serialization, binary-data, bacnet

I'm implementing a generic BACnet decoder and came across the following question, of which I can't seem to find the answer within the BACnet standard. The chapter "20.2.1.3.2 Constructed Data" does not answer my question, or I might not fully understand it.

Let's assume I have a List (SEQUENCE OF) with elements of type Record (SEQUENCE).
Said record has 4 fields, identified by context tag, where field 0 and 1 are optional.
I further assume that the order, in which those fields are serialized, can be arbitrary (because they're identified by their context tags).
The data could look like that (number indicates field / column):
[{ "3", "0", 2" }, {"1", "2", "3"}]

Over the wire, the only "structure information" I assume I get are the open / close tags for the list.
That means:

```
Open Tag List
  ctxTagColumn3, valueColumn3,
  ctxTagColumn0, valueColumn0,
  ctxTagColumn2, valueColumn2,
  ctxTagColumn1, valueColumn1,
  ctxTagColumn2, valueColumn2,
  ctxTagColumn3, valueColumn3
Close Tag List
```

How do I know, after I've read the last column data ("2") of my first list item, that I must begin decoding the second item, starting with a value for column "1"?

Which of my assumptions is wrong?

Thank you and kind regards

Pascal

Answer (score 0):

The order of elements of a SEQUENCE is always known and shall not be arbitrarily by definition. Further, not all conceivable combinations are possible to encode. Regarding BACnet, all type definitions shall be decodable universally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly; the "order" *cannot* be "arbitrary"; i.e.:

```
SEQUENCE = *ordered* collection of variables of **different** types

SEQUENCE OF = *ordered* collection of variables of **same** type
```

The tag-number for the item (SD) context-tag will be different (/possibly an incremented value/maybe +1) from the containing (PD) context-tag; so you could check for that, or better still if the tag-number value is <= 5 (/'length' value) then it's a SD context-tag for one of your items, rather than a (/the closing) PD context tag (/'type' value) delimiting the end of your items.